# Sharing class among processes in multiprocessing

Tags: python, random, multiprocessing

I implemented the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

class RandomStater():

    def __init__(self, num_per_chunks=1e7, seed = 42):
        np.random.RandomState(seed)
        self.num_per_chunks = int(num_per_chunks)
        self.d = {}
        self.i = {}
        self.random_numbers = {}

    def _choice_n(self, n):
        if self.i[n] % self.num_per_chunks == 0:
            self.random_numbers[n] = np.random.choice(n, size=self.num_per_chunks)
        self.i[n] += 1
        return self.random_numbers[n][self.i[n]]

    def choice(self, actions, p=None):
        num_actions = len(actions)
        if num_actions not in self.d:
            print('Creating action', actions)
            self.i[num_actions] = 0
            self.d[num_actions] = self._choice_n
        return actions[self.d[num_actions](num_actions)]


class SampleNumber():
    def __init__(self):
        self._random_start = RandomStater()

    def sample_number(self, _):
        return self._random_start.choice([1,2,3])
```

Basically, the class `RandomStater` is a batch version of the method `np.random.choice`, which pre-computes a large number of random samples to be used next. The second class instead is a test class to collect in sequence these random samples.
I would like to use the method `sample_number` among different processes in parallel. What should happen is that the values `self.d[num_actions]` and `self.i[num_actions]` are created just the first time the first process execute the method `choice`, while for all the other calls the counter `self.i[num_actions]` is incremented and the result is so returned very quickly.

I guess the class should be shared among the processes or something, but I am new to multiprocessing and do not well how to do that.

Up to now I tried the following without any luck:

```
ns = range(0, 2000)
rn = RandomStater()
sn = SampleNumber()
s = time.time()

p = mp.Pool(4)
got = p.map(sn.sample_number, ns)
print(got)
print(time.time() - s)
```

Comment: "What should happen is...", "I tried the following without any luck" - what is _actually_ happening? Are you getting error messages? Does your code hang? Please describe the issue

Comment: Code does not hang and no error messages, but definitely output is not what I expect: `self.i[num_actions]` and `self.d[num_actions]` are instantiated multiple times (15 times) during the execution. I expected/would like the initialisation just to happen once for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between *multithreaded*  and *parallel* random number generation.

Code like what you have in the question is not designed so much to allow multiple processes (threads) to access random numbers in parallel, as it is to reduce the time needed to generate a *serial* batch of random numbers, since more than one thread is generating them at once.  This is *multithreaded* random number generation. (See also the [sample code](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/multithreading.html) in the NumPy documentation.)

A better approach for your purposes (namely, *parallel* random number generation) is to give each process its own PRNG and to initialize those PRNGs based on a common seed.  This is explained in detail in my section "[Seeding Multiple Processes](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seeding_Multiple_Processes)", and the NumPy-specific page "[Parallel Random Number Generation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/parallel.html)".

Also, note that `numpy.random.RandomState` is now a legacy class as of NumPy 1.17; NumPy 1.17 introduces a [new random number generation system](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html) that uses so-called *bit generators*, such as PCG, and *random generators*, such as the new `numpy.random.Generator`.  It was the result of a [proposal to change the RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst).